# How to show battery percentage of a Bluetooth connected gadget (headphone)

Tags: command-line, 16.04, bluetooth, gui

Is there any way (GUI or Command line) on Ubuntu 16.04 to show battery percentage of a Bluetooth device (in this case headphones) paired and in connection with laptop?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should specify which Bluetooth device you are talking about while asking a question. There are some devices which are just having Bluetooth but don't support such additional features such as battery indicator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your device support it, you can get battery percents in console.

```
cat /sys/class/power_supply/_deviceId_/capacity
```